# Hippo cms Restart the built project

Tags: mysql, tomcat, hippocms

I have ready application that works and is connected to the mysql . I run it by the command

```
mvn -P cargo.run
```

The problem is that every time there is rebuild from zero. Can I run application without building it again? Something like

```
tomcat.dir/bin/startup.sh
```

I found these command in the

```
target/cargo/installs/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/apache-tomcat7.0.54/bin/startup.sh
```

but does not work properly (another port , lack of access , lack of application after running )

I tried to run the .war files to an external tomcat but has no connection to mysql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cargo profile should not trigger a full build. It does redeploy the artifacts. If you do a 'mvn clean' followed by 'mvn -P cargo.run' it will fail. All that should be happening is tomcat starting up.

Deploying to an external tomcat is of course supported (http://www.onehippo.org/library/deployment/create-and-deploy-a-project-distribution.html). You will need to do some configuration though.

Comment: Hi Jasper, the link doesn't seem to be working. I guess the new link should be this: http://www.onehippo.org/library/deployment/deploy-a-project-distribution.html